# Haskell Diagrams: How can I make the text bigger?

Tags: haskell, svg, haskell-diagrams

I'm using the **diagrams** haskell drawing framework. The code below is intended to produce an orange hexagon with the text "(0,0)" superimposed on it. Unfortunately, the text is tiny. I've tried to make it bigger by modifying the size of the `rect`, but no luck.

```
import Diagrams.Prelude
import Diagrams.Backend.SVG.CmdLine

diagram = mconcat [ text "(0,0)" <> rect 8 1,
                    hexagon 20 # lw 0.02 # fc orange # rotateBy (1/4) ]

main = defaultMain (pad 1.1 diagram)
```

Comment: [`scale`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/diagrams-core/latest/doc/html/Diagrams-Core-Transform.html#v:scale)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As hammar suggests, you could use `scale`, like so:

`(text "(0,0)" <> rect 8 1) # scale 5`

You can also change the font size, like

`text "(0,0)" # fontSize 5  ...`